# Set all images to landscape with bash

Tags: bash, imagemagick, identify

In the file explorer or in shotwell some images appear to be in portrait mode some are in landscape.
But the `identify` command can't differentiate them :

Landscape :

```
IMG_0064.JPG JPEG 3648x2736 3648x2736+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 3.319MB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

Portrait :

```
IMG_0108.JPG JPEG 3648x2736 3648x2736+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 3.004MB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

I use the following script to get the width and the height of my images :

[Batch crop and resize images to create thumbnails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734148/batch-crop-and-resize-images-to-create-thumbnails)

Is there a way to also get the orientation ?

### ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

What I wanted was to batch crop and resize images to create thumbnails ([solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734148/batch-crop-and-resize-images-to-create-thumbnails)) and that if I get some portrait images in the pool it rotates them.

**COMPLETE SOLUTION :**

```
#! /bin/bash
for img in *.JPG ; do
    identify=$(identify "$img")
    [[ $identify =~ ([0-9]+)x([0-9]+) ]] || \
        { echo Cannot get size >&2 ; continue ; }
    width=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    height=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
    let good_width=height+height/2

    orientation=$(identify -format '%[exif:orientation]' $img)
        if (( orientation > 1 )) ; then # crop horizontally
        echo "$img is portrait"
        name="temp"
        convert -rotate 90 "$img" "$name"
        mv "$img" "portrait_$img"
        mv "$name" "$img"
    fi

    if (( width < good_width )) ; then # crop horizontally
        let new_height=width*2/3
        new_width=$width
        let top='(height-new_height)/2'
        left=0

    elif (( width != good_width )) ; then # crop vertically
        let new_width=height*3/2
        new_height=$height
        let left='(width-new_width)/2'
        top=0
    fi

    convert -auto-orient "$img" -crop "$new_width"x$new_height+$left+$top -resize 120x80 thumb-"$img"
done
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the `-auto-orient` option to `convert` to rotate the images automatically.

If you just need to get the orientation, you have to use a format specifier on `identify`, e.g.:

```
identify -format '%[exif:orientation]' image_file.jpg
```

For more details, see the section on [Digital Photo Orientation](http://imagemagick.org/Usage/photos/#orient) in the ImageMagick documentation.

Answer (score 4):

Try the `-orient` and `-auto-orient` flags with the `convert` tool.